# SoundCloud API not working in Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle, soundcloud

I'm trying to use SoundCloud API that are available on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper)) in a test Android Project. I tried to use IntelliJ IDEA 13 and Eclipse but the problem doesn't change.

I have a simple `Activity` with a `WebView` as specified in the Facebook Connect example [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper/blob/master/src/examples/java/com/soundcloud/api/examples/FacebookConnect.java).

In IntelliJ Idea I have added my external JAR file via `Project Structure` -> `Project Settings` -> `Modules` -> `my-module` -> `Dependencies` -> `+`. I also added the dependency `compile 'com.soundcloud:java-api-wrapper:1.3.1` in my `gradle.build` File.

In Eclipse I have added it `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Libraries` -> `Add External JAR`.

I have no error during the compilation but when I launch the App from Genymotion VM it crashes reporting the following error in the LogCat.

```
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.soundcloud.api.ApiWrapper
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at com.example.soundcloudexample.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-08 17:22:40.761: E/AndroidRuntime(9509):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My `Activity` has the following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ApiWrapper wrapper = new ApiWrapper(
            SoundCloudConf.CLIENT_ID,
            SoundCloudConf.CLIENT_SECRET,
            SoundCloudConf.REDIRECT_URI,
            null /* token */);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith(SoundCloudConf.REDIRECT_URI.toString())) {
                    Uri result = Uri.parse(url);
                    String error = result.getQueryParameter("error");
                    String code = result.getQueryParameter("code");
                }
                return true;
        }
    });

     webView.loadUrl(wrapper.authorizationCodeUrl(Endpoints.FACEBOOK_CONNECT, Token.SCOPE_NON_EXPIRING).toString());
}
```

I have tried also with a real device and it seems that the API Classes are not there. Someone can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Order and export the jars which are added in java build path.

Comment: Thank you. This worked on Eclipse but not in InelliJ Idea as I don't know where to find the option. Do you know how the `gradle.build` file has to be modified to make the app working also in this IDE?

Answer (score 0):

From Android Studio go to File > Project Structure > app > Dependencies then click on the + icon and then select File Dependency and add in your .jar files and then click ok.

Gradle should then sync and update your files.